# How to access matrix alphabetically

Tags: matlab, indexing, alphabetical

I'm new to matlab, I have a matrix of 1 to 26 rows and columns. I prefer to access the matrix alphabetically, like for example a,c instead of 1,3.

Is there away to do that in matlab?

Comment: That's weird. But if you really want to do it, define constants `a=1`, `b=2` etc. I'm curious, why would you want to access the matrix alphabetically?

Comment: Can't you just char2num the alphabet and map that onto 1:26?

Comment: it's more convenient, because I'm working on pipties, where each pipties donated by a letter, so AC mean A and C pipties. So its easy to wrok with instead of 1 and 3.

Comment: Yes, char2num idea is good, I will try it.

Comment: If you can restructure your data, a [`struct`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/structures.html) or a [`containers.Map`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/map-containers.html) object might be more natural.

Comment: I have to ask. What are pipties?